# How to wait till an attribute has a different value?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

When we don't have a wait on the screen

```
<div id="divWait" style="cursor: wait; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; background: transparent; padding: 3px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
```

But when the waiting part is ongoing the display part is gone so it becomes:

```
<div id="divWait" style="cursor: wait; position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; background: transparent; padding: 3px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

the snippet i added:

```
WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("div//[@id='divWait']").getAttr‌ibute("disabled")));
```

but it didnt work

Comment: Wait for Attribute change or wait to get attribute remove as “display” get removed

Comment: i know, code for it?

Comment: Then what is the question?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? It didn't accomplish the intended task or it threw an error or ? Update your question with the info, e.g. full error message or a good description of what is or isn't happening. If the XPath you posted is what you are actually using, that's probably the error because it's not the correct syntax. You don't need an XPath here when you have an ID. What are you actually trying to do? Wait for the wait to appear on the screen or disappear or ??? Please edit your question and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

We can wait for till `display` attribute is not present

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);

wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {   
boolean isAttributeNotPresent= false;
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) 
{
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("divWait"));

if(button.isDisplayed()
{

try{
        button.getAttribute("display");
} 
catch(Exception e)
 {
isAttributeNotPresent= true;
return isAttributeNotPresent;
}}
}});
```

**Note: Ignore syntax error as I am typing from Mobile keypad**

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. To wait for the property **`display: none`** to be removed from the **style** attribute instead of *ExpectedConditions* as `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for **`visibilityOfElementLocated()`** and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#divWait")));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='divWait']")));
  ```